# C# Socket Multithreading Lambda

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, lambda

I have the following C# code:

```js
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace CTCServer
{
    class Server
    {
        //Stores the IP Adress the server listens on
        private IPAddress ip;

        //Stores the port the server listens on
        private int port;

        //Stores the counter of connected clients. *Note* The counter only gets increased, it acts as "id"
        private int clientCount = 0;

        //Defines if the server is running. When chaning to false the server will stop and disconnect all clients.
        private bool running = true;

        //Stores all connected clients.
        public List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();

        //Event to pass recived data to the main class
        public delegate void GotDataFromCTCHandler(object sender, string msg);
        public event GotDataFromCTCHandler GotDataFromCTC;

        //Constructor for Server. If autoStart is true, the server will automaticly start listening.
        public Server(IPAddress ip, int port, bool autoStart = false)
        {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;

            if (autoStart) 
                this.Run();
        }

        //Starts the server.
        public void Run()
        {
            //Run in new thread. Otherwise the whole application would be blocked
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                //Init TcpListener
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(this.ip, this.port);

                //Start listener
                listener.Start();

                //While the server should run
                while (running)
                {
                    //Check if someone wants to connect
                    if (listener.Pending())
                    {
                        //Client connection incoming. Accept, setup data incoming event and add to client list
                        Client client = new Client(listener.AcceptTcpClient(), this.clientCount);

                        //Declare event
                        client.internalGotDataFromCTC += GotDataFromClient;

                        //Add to list
                        clients.Add(client);

                        //Increase client count
                        this.clientCount++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //No new connections. Sleep a little to prevent CPU from going to 100%
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }

                //When we land here running were set to false or another problem occured. Stop server and disconnect all.
                Stop();
            }).Start(); //Start thread. Lambda \(o.o)/
        }

        //Fires event for the user
        private void GotDataFromClient(object sender, string data)
        {
            //Data gets passed to parent class
            GotDataFromCTC(sender, data);
        }

        //Send string "data" to all clients in list "clients"
        public void SendToAll(string data)
        {
            //Call send method on every client. Lambda \(o.o)/
            this.clients.ForEach(client => client.Send(data));
        }

        //Stop server
        public void Stop()
        {
            //Exit listening loop
            this.running = false;

            //Disconnect every client in list "client". Lambda \(o.o)/
            this.clients.ForEach(client => client.Close());

            //Clear clients.
            this.clients.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

- Should run not be in a loop to create new threads?
- If the first question is not true, and the lambda expression already creates new thread, at which point is new thread created? and where is the logic to decide it?

Answer (score 3):

`new Thread(` will create the new thread. The lambda is executed on the thread. Run should **not** be in a loop. Because it will create many threads.

`and the lambda expression already creates new thread`, no it will be used as the thread method.

---

The only problem is, that you don't have a reference to the thread, so you cannot wait until it is terminated.

Also you're using a bool `running` for the while loop. You'd better use a `ManualResetEvent` for it.

---

I use this as standard thread setup:

```
// signal for terminating the thread.
private ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private Thread _thread;

public void Start()
{
    ManualResetEvent threadStarted = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    _thread = new Thread(() => 
    {
        threadStarted.Set();

        while(!_terminating.WaitOne(0))
        {
            // do your thing here.
        }
    }); 

    _thread.Start();
    threadStarted.WaitOne();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _terminating.Set();
    _thread.Join();
}
```

---

One remark here is: Should you use Threaded clients or async sockets.

- Threaded clients: client count <= 10
- async sockets: client count > 10

The problem with a server is, that your not in charge of how many clients are connecting.

---

Some pseudo code how to setup your tcp-server and running threads for each client.

```
public class Server
{

    // signal for terminating the thread.
    private ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private List<ClientHandler> _clients = new List<ClientHandler>();

    public void Start()
    {
        ManualResetEvent threadStarted = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        _thread = new Thread(() => 
        {
            threadStarted.Set();

            // create listener.....

            while(!_terminating.WaitOne(0))
            {
                // do your thing here.

                // accept socket
                var socket = _listenerSocket.Accept();

                ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(socket);
                _clients.Add(handler);

            }
        }); 

        _thread.Start();
        threadStarted.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _terminating.Set();
        _thread.Join();
    }

}


public class ClientHandler
{
    // signal for terminating the thread.
    private ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
    {
        ManualResetEvent threadStarted = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        _thread = new Thread(() => 
        {
            threadStarted.Set();

            while(!_terminating.WaitOne(0))
            {
                // do your thing here.

                // accept socket
                var bytesReaded = socket.Read(.....);
                // handle data....
            }
        }); 

        _thread.Start();
        threadStarted.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _terminating.Set();
        _thread.Join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, for every new socket connection there shoulw be a new thread right? This code snippet only creates one thread so this server is not multithreading? There should be a thread for every new connection right?

Comment: Yes, you should create a new thread for each connected socket or **use async sockets**. A thread for each socket is way faster (about 1.5 times) but is not very scalable. It will consume a thread each client.

Comment: Then, my code snippet will only create 1 thread right? So it isn't a multithreaded socket server and can't accept more than one connection right? How could i change that so it accept more than one connection

Comment: Right, You're only accepting the clientsockets, they are not handled. So your listener is on a separate thread, You clients aren't handled. So you need to create a separate class that will spawn a thread for each client. You should pass the socket to the constructor of that per client class. The loop you wanted, won't solve it. Because you should only have one thread for listening.

Comment: Thanks, im understanding a bit better now... But how can i detect a new connection and then start a new thread with it?

Comment: Hey thanks man! But why you need a thread to accept sockets, could you not just simply add them in a while loop without a thread?

Comment: Sure you can, but you might not want to block your gui thread.

Comment: Thanks man, now im understanding right, finally i understood basic threading + sockets

Comment: I have a question, socket.Accept() si blocking, so what will happen if 2 clients connect at the same exact moment?

Comment: The second will wait until the first is accepted and the listener thread returns to the Accept mode. So, it will wait. _(just creating a new thread and return to accepting, doesn't take long)_ ....If many clients are connecting, you can set a limit to accept-waiters with the backlog argument of [Socket.Listen()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen(v=vs.110).aspx)